# Azure CLI for app registration creation from Azure DevOps - Insufficient privileges

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-cli, azure-cli2

I tried to create app registration in Azure AD with Azure CLI from Azure DevOps pipeline. Thanks to the task `AzureCLI@2 (preview)`. But it's giving below error.

> "az : ERROR: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."

However when I run this script from Azure portal Cloud Shell, it works fine.

Do you have any idea about how to fix that?

Thank you

Comment: Make sure the `service connection` you selected in `AzureCLI@2 (preview)` task dropdown has permissions to create App Registration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However when I run this script from Azure portal Cloud Shell, it works fine.

In azure cloud shell, it uses the credential of the user account which you logged in to the cloud shell. If it works, it just means your user account has permission to create the AD App(App registration).

> Do you have any idea about how to fix that?

When you create the Azure Resource Manager service connection to use the `AzureCLI@2 (preview)`, the system will create an AD App for you automatically, check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/azure-rm-endpoint?view=azure-devops#what-happens-when-you-create-a-resource-manager-service-connection).
 If you use this service connection with `AzureCLI@2 (preview)`, it will use the credential of the service principal of the AD App in your tenant. For the concept of service principal and AD App, see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/app-objects-and-service-principals).

To fix the issue, navigate to the `Azure Active Directory` in the portal -> `App registrations` -> `All applications` -> find the application corresponding to the service connection, its name should be like `organizationname-projectname-513f22f1-befd-xxxxxxcfe90f1`. Then click it -> add the permission like the screenshots(**Note**: your user account need the admin role to click the **`Grant admin consent`** button, e.g. `Global admin` ).

[image]

[image]

After granting the permission, wait for a while, the service principal of the service connection will be able to create the AD App, the Azure CLI task should work fine.

Comment: I may be missing something but MS says Azure AD Graph API is on the deprecation path (from 30th June 2020. However granting Microsoft Graph's Application.ReadWrite.All throws insuffient priveleges when creating an app reg. Yet granting the Azure AD Graph Application.ReadWrite.All permission works a treat. Maybe this will be useful for someone also caught out by this.